# Picture appears dark after editing in Mac

Tags: photo-editing, macintosh, adobe-rgb

I have been using a Macbook Pro [2011 model] lately for Photo editing [mainly wildlife/nature]. I found the photos which looked good after editing[Photoshop CS5] in Mac were **dark** when viewed in other laptops/PC. I thought Macbook's were the best for Editing stuffs.

Is this in anyway related to rgb-color-space?

Comment: Are both screens calibrated? If so with what software, If not do that first.

Comment: @RHall Used Photoshop for editing. And no, the screens are not calibrated. Let me check. Thanks for the lead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using calibrated screens, then you will get this kind of issue.  The Mac screen may be particularly bright and if it isn't calibrated to be comparable to the other screens, then you will end up mixing the image darker than in needs to be to look correct on the other displays.

Building an ICC profile for all the displays will allow for the color consistency to be maximized between displays, although there will still likely be differences because of differences in the color gamuts supported by each display (unless you choose to limit the good displays to the gamuts of the lesser displays, which I don't personally recommend in most scenarios.)

Comment: Thanks. I changed the display profile to 'Adobe RGB(1998)'. Now the screen looks more cool [bluish tint].

Comment: @Sreejith - to really make it fit, you will need to actually get a calibration unit that can measure the screens.  Otherwise color will continue to be very inconsistent.  There is a fair bit of variety from screen to screen, though if you have cheap TN LCD panels, you will get variation just based on the angle you look at them.

Comment: The "Adobe RGB (1998)" profile is a color space profile, not a monitor profile. Don't use that. You need a calibration tool like those from X-Rite and Datacolor.